# Installing Reaver 1.4

Tags: command-line, make

I am trying to install reaver 1.4, but when I run `./configure ; make`
I get this message at the end

```
int ret_val = EXIT_FAILURE, r = 0;
```

I have searched a fair bit and cannot find an answer, any help would be appreciated. I apologize if this has been answered and I've just failed to find it.

Comment: It looks like code getting echoed out. Does the app work fine? If the app works, I wouldn't worry unless it starts acting weird.

Answer (score 7):

Reaver 1.4 can be installed from the default repositories in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu and also in Ubuntu 18.10 when it is released. To install Reaver in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install reaver
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it all from beginning and follow these steps

Run the following commands(in "Bold") in the terminal.

Step 1: `sudo -s`

Type your password.
Installing Dependencies and required tools.

Step 2: `sudo apt-get install libpcap-dev sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev libpcap0.8-dev`

Now we have the Dependencies and required tools. We can download the Reaver Source and Install it.

Step 3: `wget https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/reaver-wps/reaver-1.4.tar.gz`

Extracting the tar package.

Step 4: `tar -xzvf reaver-1.4.tar.gz`

Compiling and making install.

Step 5: `cd reaver-1.4`

Step 6: `cd src`

Step 7: `./configure`

Step 8: `make`

Step 9: `sudo make install`

Hope it helped